# Print Window Is closing immediately after clicking print property window

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {
        var divElements = document.getElementById('invc').innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><style>#invc{width:50%;align:center;}</style> </head><body>" + divElements + "</body></html>";
        window.print();        
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

I am using the above script to print a particular div.

The div is properly working by opening a window along with the print property

But as soon as I hit close button of print property window the other window is also getting closed.

I don't want that window to be closed.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point, but is this your problem? `window.close();`

Comment: Try not calling `window.close();`

Comment: If i remove window.close(); also same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily:

```
function printElement(id) {
        window.frames["print"].document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    window.frames["print"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print"].window.print();
}
```